# How to return API response to conversation in Dialogflow Webhook

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I have a Dialogflow Webhook fulfillment integration, which does a GET request to an API i have set up. But i can't seem to get the API's response as text in my conversation.

The API does receive a http GET request and returns a response with statuscode 200.
If i do the same request in my browser this is the result:

```
{
    "avmid": "1011GZ 18",
    "straat": "Snoekjesgracht",
    "postcode": "1011GZ",
    "stad": "AMSTERDAM",
    "provincienaam": "Noord-Holland",
    "date": "2013-12-30",
    "koopsom": 199800,
    "koopsom2018q2": 333849
}
```

I have tried several things but i don't seem to be able to get it to work.
This is my JavaScript:

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function address_api_request (agent) {

    let postcode = agent.parameters.zipcode;
    let housenumber = agent.parameters.housenumber;

    let avmid = postcode.toString()+'+'+housenumber.toString();
    let url = 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XX/api/1011GZ+18';


    var http = require('http');
    http.get(url, function(response) {

            var body = '';
            response.on('data', function(d) {
                body += d;
            });
            response.on('end', function() {

                var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
                agent.add(parsed.toString());
            });
        });
    }


  function welcome (agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
    agent.add(agent.request_.body.queryResult.fulfillmentText);
  }

  function fallback (agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('company.woningwaarde-get-address-api', address_api_request);
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

The intents work, and if i replace the address_api_request function with the underneath code it returns "test:

```
function address_api_request (agent) {
  agent.add('test');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

The first is that if you are using Dialogflow's built-in editor, it is using Firebase Cloud Functions under the covers. The default level of Firebase Cloud Functions does not allow network access outside of Google's cloud.

You can resolve this by upgrading the project to Firebase's [Blaze Plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/), which does require a credit card on file and charges per-use, however there is a free tier which is more than sufficient for reasonable testing, and even some light use under production. Once your action has been approved, you'll be eligible to receive Google Cloud credits which may be used for this purpose.

The other problem is that you have an asynchronous function (the `http.get()`), but you aren't using a Promise to handle the function and let the `handleRequest()` method know that it needs to wait for the function to resolve before returning a result. If you are using async functions, the Dialogflow library requires that you return a Promise from the function.

You have a few choices for how to handle this. First, you can wrap your call to `http.get()` as part of [creating a new Promise object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and in your `end` handler, send the message as you've indicated and then call the `resolve` parameter that you need to accept in the Promise handler. Easier, however, would be to use a library such as [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) which wraps much of this for you and lets you get a result as part of a `then()` clause, where you would then handle it.

I haven't tested it, but your code might then look something like this:

```
function address_api_request (agent) {

  let postcode = agent.parameters.zipcode;
  let housenumber = agent.parameters.housenumber;

  let avmid = postcode.toString()+'+'+housenumber.toString();
  let url = 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XX/api/1011GZ+18';

  const rp = require('request-promise-native');
  var options = {
    uri: url,
    json: true
  };
  return rp( options )
    .then( body => {
      // Since json was set true above, it parses it for you
      // You wouldn't really want to send back the whole body
      agent.add( body );
    })
    .catch( err => {
      console.log('Problem with request', err );
      agent.add( "Uh oh, something went wrong" );
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response, but it doesn't work unfortunately.
I already have a Blaze Plan so that should be fine. And as i mentioned, the API is receiving a request and sending a response back.

The problem is in the fact that i can't get the JSON response from the API back into the conversation. With your solution the API doesn't get a request.

Might this have something to do with the promise? Do i need to add some code somewhere else to handle that?

Comment: It is possible that my code has an error - as I said, I didn't test it (I don't have your URL), but based it off code that I used that worked. I've added a catch block, and you can add additional debugging to see what is going on or check the documentation to make sure you don't need to set anything additional. You don't need to add anything ot handle the Promise you're returning, since you're using `handleIntent()`. You don't need to use request-promise, but you *do* need to use and return a Promise if you're doing async work.